# jQuery : Swipe or Click to the same action

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just a question who dosen't need code. I want to make an action if user clicks on a button or if he swipes (via jQuery Mobile) and I was asking myself is there is an another way to do this without create a function and call it on event listeners.

I can't use the method `.on` because I am not calling the same DOM Element.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it mean "...I am not calling the same DOM element"? Can you please explain little bit

Comment: Yes you do need code. See, we do not get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the same function as the event listener for both, or the event listeners of both will have to call your function.

E.g.

```
$(swipable).on("swipe", action);
$(clickable).on("click", action);

function action() {
}
```